# What kind of permission do I need if I'm part of an IAM group to create an EMR cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-emr, aws-permissions

I tried to create an EMR cluster as my user is part of an IAM group on AWS, but I cannot, it says
"You do not have permissions to create roles". "Unable to create cluster"[image]

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EMR requires two IAM Roles to be created:

- `EMR_DefaultRole`: [Service role for Amazon EMR (EMR role) - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-role.html) defines the allowable actions for Amazon EMR when provisioning resources and performing service-level tasks that are not performed in the context of an EC2 instance running within a cluster. For example, the service role is used to provision EC2 instances when a cluster launches.
- `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`: [Service role for cluster EC2 instances (EC2 instance profile) - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-role-for-ec2.html) assigned to every EC2 instance in an Amazon EMR cluster when the instance launches. Application processes that run on top of the Hadoop ecosystem assume this role for permissions to interact with other AWS services.

If these roles are not present when an Amazon EMR cluster is launched, then the Amazon EMR service will create these roles on your behalf. However, **this requires that you have sufficient permissions to create the roles**.

Your error messages says `You do not have permissions to create roles`. Therefore, you will need to **ask one of your Administrators to create the roles**.

The roles can be created by using the AWS CLI [`aws emr create-default-roles`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-default-roles.html) command.